# regex optional part in prefix, but do not include it in matches if it present

Tags: regex

Problem is easier to be seen in code then described I got following regex

> ```
>  (?<=First(Second)?)\w{5}
> ```

and following sample data

> FirstSecondText1
>   FirstText2

I only want matches `Text1` & `Text2` , I get 3 though, `Secon` is added, and I don't want that.
Played around, cant seem to get it to work.

Comment: Why `[\w\W]{5}`? This makes only sense if you're on JavaScript and want to match newline characters, too. Otherwise, just use `.{5}` (with or without setting the `(?s)` dot-matches-all flag).

Comment: ive edited already, was testing on some multiline data hence that, while we are at it: is there a better way to capture anything then [\w\W]?

Comment: Yes, just use the dot together with the DOTALL option (details vary between regex implementations).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an additional negative lookahead:

```
(?<=First(Second)?)(?!Second)\w{5}
```

If you want to avoid using `Second` twice, you could do it without lookaround and take the result of the first capturing group:

```
First(?:Second)?(\w{5})
```

Comment: ooh cool thanks, and its impossible other way right? in my case Second is pretty big... and regex will benefit if it was only used one time

Comment: yeah thats always an option but I need my results from question. I am thinking there must be a way to use a reference on (second) capture using something like balanced groups maybe?

Comment: problem is, I am getting "Secon" with this, looks like this just doesn't work, balance group value is empty when it stops before S character and suffix is empty too.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I hadn't thought this through. I'm going back to my previous answer.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Not to nitpick, but the first regex would fail to match last `Second` in the input text `FirstSecondSecond`.

Comment: it is fine for my case because in actual text second is never repeated, but yeah it will fail for such text

Answer (score 1):

You can try this regex `(?<=First(Second)?)\w{5}$`. All you have to do is to add a `$` in the end so that the regex would not match the text `Secon`. You can use this as long as you are sure of the pattern that comes at the end of the input text. In this case it is `\w{5}$`

Comment: Good idea, if nothing actually follows after those five characters.

Comment: If some text follows those 5 characters, then `\w{5}$` has to be replaced with a new pattern that describes that particular text in a way that excludes matching of the optional prefix (`Second`) while matching itself.

Comment: in reality \w{5} is another complex regex that can occur 1+ times with no known ending..

Comment: @ValentinKuzub It can be any complex regex, all that matters is, can it exclude the matching of optional prefix (`Second` in this case) at the start and can it match `$` at the end. Even if you use double lookaround like `(?<=First(Second)?)(?!Second)\w{5}`, it would fail in the case when the input text is something like `FirstSecondSecond`.